# HTML : Common header and footer files

Tags: html

I have several html file which has same url reference in `<head>` tag. For example

```
<head><script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/tasklistform.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script></head>
```

This script references i want to move in file want to reference that file in all html files. I am using plain html.

Comment: If you converted your files to a .php extension you'd be able to do what you're looking to do. I don't think it's possible with a .html ext..

Comment: you are suggesting my file html file should be renamed with extension .php (for say first.php) and then need to create one php file (for say footer.php) and inside that file i need to specify these script reference and then that footer.php file should be refer in first.php.

Comment: That's how i'd do it personally.. So say header.php (basic markup) index.php (your page content) footer.php (footer and script tags) then simply include both the header and footer.

Comment: Can you please give some url which explain this concept...

Comment: Sure: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp here's the basic concept of how to use them.

Comment: question gives the impression that you want to move js reference to one file and use that file in all html file.
but as in subject it looks like you want to have common header and footer html template.
so is it js or html you want to move

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object tag:

```
<object type="text/html" data="common_html.inc"></object>
```

In the example your common code would go in a file called "common_html.inc".